# Composer and Travis Ci with Magento modules

Tags: extensions, composer, development, travis

We have an existing module that contains a composer.json file which is working well on its own but we are also wanting to set-up travis-ci with this extension.

When the travis-ci runs it fails with the error.

```
magento root dir "" is not valid
```

I think this error is happening because we are actually using the extension's composer.json file rather than a clean composer.json file for a Magento instance.

Does anyone know how the travis.yml file should be set-up for an extension? Does anyone have an extension that is successfully being tested via travis-ci that I could use as an example?

Our extension: https://github.com/sitewards/B2BProfessional

Another broken example: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/FrontendMonitoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it appears that you need to do one of the following:

1. Add a `magento-root-dir` into your `composer.json` for the magento module. This will only be used when in project context and not for a single module,
2. Update the `.travis.yml` so that it creates its own composer.json and adds all the modules required,